# Is it possible to transfer files to smartphone during tethering?

Tags: android, usb, android-wifi, file-transfer, tethering

I have wi-fi source that could be used by smartphone. To work on my notebook I connect to internet through wi-fi by smartphone and use usb cable tethering. Internet works, but I didn't find way to transfer files to smartphone. I need to interrupt tethering and transfer files.
Is it possible to transfer files without interrupting tethering?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on Android if you use another file transfer protocol instead of MTP. For example, you could run an ssh server on your phone - SSHHelper app works fine, then use SFTP from your computer to browse your phone's files - I like WinScp on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend: **[NitroShare](https://nitroshare.net/)**

Benefits:

- It's **open-source**. Therefore they are not planning to earn money from it, i.e. it will not show ads, it will not ask for extra permissions, and its source code is open to everyone.
- ... and this means it's also **free**.
- According to [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.nitroshare.android/) it has **no "anti-features"**, i.e. it does not depend on commercial software, services or libraries, it does not even use Google Play Services and it does not connect to any cloud or any commercial server.
- It's **easy to use** and **powerful**, it detects any device in a local network automatically and you can send single or multiple files or whole directories at once.
- It works with any kind of network, which means it **works with tethering**. I use it to exchange files between my laptop and my Android phone *without interrupting tethering*.
- It's **bidirectional**: you can send files from PC to phone *and viceversa*.
- It's **cross-platform**: it's available for Android devices and for Windows, Linux and Mac-OS.

Some links:

- [Download from Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nitroshare.android)
- [Download from F-Droid](https://nitroshare.net/)
- [Desktop version](https://nitroshare.net/)
- [Source code](https://github.com/nitroshare/nitroshare-desktop)

Comment: Works great! It would be good to add your affiliation with the software, though ;)

Comment: haha, I am just a happy user :)

Answer (score 0):

Download **ES FILE EXPLORER** on your phone go to NETWORK tab and then view on pc or remote manager then click on start it gets you an ip address type it either on internet explorer or on THIS PC tab when you lunch it